# Black box terminology

Tags: algorithms, terminology, time-complexity

Can we use the term "black box" to speak about an algorithm which has a polynomial complexity but for which we don't know exactly how are made the calculations?

In fact I would like to explain that we assume that an algorithm cannot be executed incrementally, i.e., having a part of the input, for instance the first 50%, we cannot progress the computations of this algorithm.

Can the term "black box" be understood in this sense?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. But "black box" usually means something whose workings are unknowable; we only see the input and output.

Comment: Ore you looking for the term "oracle"?